# Set a non-continuous cells as a Range

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I need to set a non-continuous cells as a Range. 
This lines works as it should `ws.Range("A2:A5,D2:D5")` 
But, when I used the last row as a variable, I got a wrong range. 
I wish to keep using the `Range` object and not Cells. 
**Note**, I just using `Select` to see the end result (not using on the actual code).

```
Sub Range_Test()

   Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
   
   Dim lastRow As Long
   lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   
   ws.Range("A2:A5,D2:D5").Select    '--> this works correctly
   
   ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow, "D2:D" & lastRow).Select
 
End Sub
```

Comment: the comma has to be part of the string `ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",D2:D" & lastRow).Select`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma has to be part of the string
`ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow & ",D2:D" & lastRow).Select` to define a range.

The way you wrote it, you set the the top left cell and the bottom right corner of the range.